# How to allow the contecnt on my page scroll while the background is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Guys i want my page to scroll the content in it (which are just texts) i created a code to form a web page but after i created it, the background is fixed (which is what i want) but it does not allow the text on the page to scroll up or down it just fixed there with background, here are the codes below

```
$('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;min-height:100%;text-align: center;z-index:100000;background:url(http://weezywap.xtgem.com/B/Bbg/23.jpg);" class=""><section class="top-bar-section"> <ul class="right tabs">  <li class="divider"></li> <li class="balanceli"><span id="balance">421.79258102</span> BTC</li><li class="divider"></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logout_link"><img src="/images/logout.png" border="0" style="padding-bottom:5px;" alt="LOGOUT" title="LOGOUT"></a></li> <li class="divider"></li></ul></section><div  class="large-12 large-centered small-12 small-centered columns" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important;"> <div id="main_content" class="large-9 small-7 large-centered new_border_shadow columns"><div id="deposit_withdraw_container" class="deposit_withdraw_container"><div class="row center" style="margin:0; margin-top:20px; padding-top:10px;"> <style> p#demo{color:white;}</style><table style="margin:0 auto;"><tr><th>BOT STATISTICS</th></tr><tr><td>balance</td><td id="balance_b"></td></tr><tr><td>win</td><td id="roundwin_b"></td><p id="demo">COUNTDOWN TO YOUR SCRIPT EXPIRY DATE</p>
```

please what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the style `overflow: auto` to your fixed div